# dynamic number of pointers inside a struct

Tags: c++, dynamic, struct

friends

I have a struct which contains pointers. Different pointers will connect to different data types. The problem is that I don't know how many the current struct will connect to, and what those data structures would be.

For example,

```
struct root
{
  branch1 *a;
  branch2 *b;
  branch3 *c;
  /// ...
};
```

Branch1, 2, 3 are different structs themselves. But I don't know for now how many branch1, 2, 3 i will connect the root to. Therefore, is there a way to dynamically introduce extra pointers into the struct if later I know how many the root will connect to?

Let me be more specific.
The root is the wire between different logic gates.
The branch1, 2, 3 actually points to the gates which is driven by this wire.
Since there are different gates (different number of inputs, different function), and i don't know what is the fanout of the wire now.

---------------My current Approach----------------------------------

Before i am going to some mature data structure like vector as suggested by some friends,

Currently i am trying using some inherent class and polymorphism to implement.

All wires are inherent from base wire but with different fanout

All gates are inherent from base gates which has largest number of inputs, inherent gates use some of them to implement the gate function

Am still trying.

Comment: Can you give more detail about what this data structure does? You very likely need to look at other solutions to your problem since C++ does not support this kind of thing directly.

Comment: Why not ``vector<BaseClass *> S``, where a, b, and c are added via ``S.push_back(a);``? Then subclass ``BaseClass``.

Comment: Either your branch structs share some commonalities, in which case you could introduce an inheritance hierarchy and have a dynamic container of base pointers, or they don't, in which case I imagine that your design is broken in some fundamental way.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/heterogeneous-list.html
It boils down to e.g. `std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<BranchBase>>`

Answer (score 1):

You can always use inheritance and vectors.

Example

```
struct Branch{

}

struct Branch1 : public Branch{

}

struct root{

  vector<branch*> branches;
};
```

[More on this here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtype_polymorphism)

Answer (score 0):

Make a Class called Branch. Make all the other classes derive from Branch like Branch1, Branch2, ..

In your struct, make an array or vector of pointers to Branch as follows:

```
struct root{

    vector<branch *>branches;

...... };
```

Comment: The whole point of *dynamically* changing the number of pointers is lost here. If you're manually doing malloc/realloc, this is not C++. C++ has `vector` to do that for you.

Comment: @chris i have modified my code. although the question was not about vector/pointers, it was about showing him a dynamic way

Answer (score 0):

You should instead be using a base class (or an Interface in java terms) for all your different branch types, and store pointers to that in a data structure which can grow dynamically (lists or vectors in C++ STL to be more simple).

```
class BaseBranch
{
...
};

class Branch1 : public BaseBranch
{
...
};

using namespace std;
list<BaseBranch*>mybranches;
```

If you need to access elements by position instead of always starting from the first element of the list, I'd suggest std::vector

```
using namespace std;
vector<BaseBranch*>mybranches;
```

EDIT: Fixed a typo - thanks to Linuxios

Comment: What's with the `void*` at the end? Why not `BaseBranch*`?

Comment: @Linuxios - Initially I was planning to suggest using void* pointers, but then I realized he was using C++ and came with the inheritance idea. But somehow I missed to modify everywhere ;)

Comment: Sure. I've had plenty of C++ answers where I've ended up suggesting something like `void*` or raw C arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some more detailed explanation of why you need the inheritance solutions:

1. C++ code generation generated asm code has large amount of compile-time offset-like constants which finds the data in c++ program from memory.
2. C++ has important feature called sizeof(T). Every type supports it, and it documents the behaviour of c++ types. It's return value is compile-time constants, which cannot change on runtime.
3. sizeof(root) obviously has the same restriction. Like your struct, every c++ type behaves the same way.
4. The only way to go past the restriction is via array version of new. It goes past the c++ type system and the result is a pointer, not a type that contains all the data.
5. std::vector internally solves the problem by keeping two separate memory areas. Again the actual data is not inside c++ type.
6. So the only way to do runtime-variable amounts of data is by jumping from one type to another in runtime. If you have just one type, it won't be enough.
7. The inheritance solution with a base class and possibly virtual functions is a way to jump from one type to another. There are other ways to do the same kind of jumping.